# AutoMapper .NET6 C#10 Blazor WASM PWA

Tags: blazor, automapper, webassembly, .net-6.0, c#-10.0

I had a problem that the AutoMapper worked in .NET5 with in Program.cs ->

`services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Startup));`

New Blazored WASM PWA do not have a Startup class. So the AutoMapper failed.

Answer (score 2):

.NET6 C#10

in Program.cs ->

`builder.Services.AddAutoMapper(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());`

AutoMapper is working fine with C#10 EF6 .NET6.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this problem in `.NET6` and resolved it by adding the package

`AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection`